# Update MySQL using a regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table called `location` with a field `area`. This field can contain various types of values.

Example: `London`, `New York`, `Tokoyo`, `3`, `10`, `99`, `149`, `2743`, etc.

Using a regular expression I want to update this field if it containes a 1 or 2 digit number by adding the word `Area`. So using the example above, the update will result in `Area 3`, `Area 10`, `Area 99`.

The rest of the values will be ignored as they don't meet the criteria.
Hopefully that makes sence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this, using the [**`REGEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator :

```
UPDATE  location
SET     area = concat('Area ', area)
WHERE   area REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,2}$'
```